# How to get the amount of available-light in the area surrounding the iPhone using Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

I want to know the amount of light available in the area surrounding the iPhone so that I can change my App's background.

I searched for it and found "ProximityMonitoring" and "Ambient Light Sensor".

ProximityMonitoring is not going to fulfill my need, Ambient Light Sensor can fulfill my need but the problem with it is, this API is private if I use this API Apple would definitely reject my app.

There is another way to do this (i.e) capturing a image using device camera and getting the luminosity of the image but this will not fulfill my need as I want to change background in a runtime environment.

Those answers I saw(similar to this question's) are atleast "2 years old". I want to know that after the release of iOS7 did Apple make this "Ambient Light Sensor" API public? if yes how to use that API. Or there is a better way to do this, "Please enlighten me".

(For that runtime thing IMO NSNotification would helpful (i.e) this notification will fire every time when the light around the device changes).

Note : My deployment target is 7.0 and I want to do this in runtime.